# mysql concatenating json path with number variable fails

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

Following statement will exexute without error:

```
select json_contains_path('{"12":12}','one',concat('$."',12,'"'));
```

But following will fail with error: `cant create json with binary string`:

```
prepare stmt from 'select json_contains_path(\'{"12":12}\',\'one\',concat(\'$."\',?,\'"\'))';
set @n=12;
execute stmt using @n;
```

Why is that? I think they are the same thing with variable replacement

Comment: If the prepared statement change to `prepare stmt from 'select json_contains_path(\'{"12":12}\',\'one\',concat(\'$."\',convert(? using utf8mb4),\'"\'))';`, it'll succeed

Comment: Does `set @n='12'` work for you?

Comment: @Paul Spiegel, It works too. I don't know why number variables behave differently compared to using numbers directly inside the concat function.